# Using mongoose .save() is not working well

Tags: mongoose, nodes

I am using mongoose package for nodejs. when I find after save the document in db, console log of document is saving well. but actually in db the value 
is not saving. Please let me know where I mistaken

My sample code is bellow

```
tag_service.findOne({user_id : req.body.userId}).exec(function(err, service_doc) {
 if (!err && service_doc != null) {
      service_doc.profile_tags.contacts_info = true
      service_doc.save(function(err, tg_doc) {
       console.log(err, tg_doc)(here displaying well,But not saved in DB) 
      })
    }
  })
```

Comment: here you're sending _id object with the document , it wont save new one ,the old document is overwritten in service_doc

Comment: It will work, when I find by _id. Am I correct?

Comment: the code is correct, you may be missing something else, make sure what you are looking at right place

Comment: var thingSchema = new Schema(service_doc, { strict: false });
var thing = new Thing({ iAmNotInTheSchema: true });
thing.save();

Comment: In between, getting service_doc and saving doc, I have another two more db calls